# Problem with sending 2nd command code to device througth Modbus TCP

Tags: c++, tcp, rfid, modbus

I'm beginner and I have trouble with sending messages through Modbus TCP. 
I create win socket with RFID read/write head on port 502, then I send 1st command 10h (write_multiple_registers) to head and I receive reply without problem... After that I think that is ready to send next command (10h again or 03h (read_holding_registers) but it doesn't work. I must create a new socket and then it works till first command is executed... It seems that RFID head doesn't receive the command. I usually use send() and recv() functions. I tried to test device by tester like SimplyModbus and everything works without problem. Does anyone have any experiance with this problem? Thank you very much for your help!

```
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


#pragma comment (lib,"WS2_32.lib")

using namespace std;
using std::string;
typedef SSIZE_T ssize_t;

#endif //PCH_H

bool modbus::modbus_connect() {
    if(HOST == "" || PORT == 0) {
        std::cout << "Missing Host and Port" << std::endl;
        return false;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Found Proper Host "<< HOST << " and Port " <<PORT <<std::endl;
    }

    WSAData data;
    sockaddr_in _server;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
    if (wsResult != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Error Create Socket" << wsResult << endl;
        return false;
    }

    _socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(_socket == -1) {
        std::cout <<"Error Opening Socket" <<std::endl;
        return false;
    } else {
        std::cout <<"Socket Opened Successfully" << std::endl;
    }

    u_long iMode = 0;
    wsResult = ioctlsocket(_socket, FIONBIO, &iMode);

    _server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    _server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(HOST.c_str());
    _server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    wsResult = ::bind(_socket,(sockaddr*)&_server, sizeof(_server));


    if (connect(_socket, (sockaddr*)&_server, sizeof(_server)) < 0) {
        std::cout<< "Connection Error" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::cout<< "Connected" <<std::endl;
    _connected = true;
    return true;
}

ssize_t modbus::modbus_send(uint8_t *to_send, int length)
{
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    FD_SET(_socket, &fds);
    int i = select(32, NULL, &fds, NULL, &tv); // write
    if (i <= 0)
    {
        printf("select - error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    _msg_id++;

    wsResult = send(_socket, (const char*)to_send, (size_t)length, 0);
    if (wsResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
    }

    return 0;
}

ssize_t modbus::modbus_receive(uint8_t *buffer)
{
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    FD_SET(_socket, &fds);
    int i = select(32, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv); //read
    if (i <= 0)
    {
        printf("no TCP response received\n");
        closesocket(_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    wsResult = recv(_socket, (char *)buffer, 1024, 0);
    if (wsResult == 0)
    {
        printf("received failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your device or development kit has any examples? Can you elaborate on the device models? I see you are on Windows.

Comment: Hi, I have only manual of RFID device [link](https://files.pepperl-fuchs.com/webcat/navi/productInfo/doct/tdoct1794f_eng.pdf?v=20140701110741)

Comment: All you currently show is the implementation of connect, send and receive which are basically wrapper around the systems socket+connect, send and recv. It is unclear how these functions work together in your larger code but exactly this kind of properly working together seems to be the problem in your question. In other words: your question is missing essential details which are needed to help you.

Comment: Finnally I 'm using library from GIT [link](https://github.com/fanzhe98/modbuspp). First time I call command 10h and then 03h for reading registers in device. The command is executed, but 2nd one no.

Comment: Without further explanation your question will stay unanswered, please elaborate on your SDK, how are you using it, and provide links to it. The link to the device helps but your problem is not a hardware problem as it seems you need to provide further details. Also update your post with your code as you seem to have improved it. You know your stuff, but people here only knows what you give them to read.

Comment: Furthermore, the link you posted specifically says it WILL NOT work on Windows unless you adapt it by rewriting code, have you done that?